# RestKit Dynamically Map Relationship Name based on Value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I am using RestKit to parse JSON and map it into Core Data NSManagedObjects. Here is a sample JSON.

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "description": "...",
            "subject_type": "photo",
            "subject": {
                "id": 1,
                "thumb_url": "...",
                "medium_url": "...",
                "large_url": "..."
            }
        },
        {
            "description": "...",
            "subject_type": "user",
            "subject": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "...",
                "followers": "..."
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Using `RKObjectMappingProvider` and `RKManagedObjectMapping` I am mapping the `"events"` array into separate Core Data `Event` objects. This works fine.

Now `Event` has two relationships on it `User` and `Photo`. Now I need to map the subject array to the proper Core Data object based on the value of `"subject_type"`and set that to the correct relationship on `Event`.

I tried using `RKDynamicObjectMapping` but I don't know how to specify that for a "dynamic relationship". I need some way to set the name of the destination relationship based on the value of `subject_type`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I wish someone answered the actual question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RestKit,  `RKDynamicMapping` also allows the use of a specified block to do more complex dynamic mapping operations like the one that you describe.   The specific method that gives this capability is called `setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock`

Here are some docs on that method :
http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKDynamicMapping.html#//api/name/setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:

The RestKit unit tests illustrate some simple cases for this method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should be able to utilize `RKDynamicObjectMapping` (see [Object Mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping)). You could create a User mapping and a Photo mapping and then use your `RKDynamicObjectMapping` like this:

```
[dynamicMapping setObjectMapping:userMapping 
              whenValueOfKeyPath:@"subject_type" 
                       isEqualTo:@"user"];
[dynamicMapping setObjectMapping:photoMapping 
              whenValueOfKeyPath:@"subject_type" 
                       isEqualTo:@"photo"];
```

Comment: Now how do I set this on the `Event` entity so that it uses the proper relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem. Tracing through RestKit, it looks like it's trying to apply all object mappings to all relationships in an RKDynamicMapping instance. See `applyRelationshipMappings` in RKMappingOperation.m

I came up with a solution that is a hack, but didn't require I modify restkit code heavily.

In RKMappingOperation.m, I modified the following method:

```
destinationObjectForMappingRepresentation:parentRepresentation:withMapping:inRelationship:
```

I added the following code (starting with the comment) that checks whether the destination of the relationship is the same type of object as is being applied, and only proceeds if it matches. (This has not undergone rigorous testing, but is working in my particular use case.)

```
- (id)destinationObjectForMappingRepresentation:(id)representation parentRepresentation:(id)parentRepresentation withMapping:(RKMapping *)mapping inRelationship:(RKRelationshipMapping *)relationshipMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *concreteMapping = nil;
    if ([mapping isKindOfClass:[RKDynamicMapping class]]) {
        concreteMapping = [(RKDynamicMapping *)mapping objectMappingForRepresentation:representation];
        if (! concreteMapping) {
            RKLogDebug(@"Unable to determine concrete object mapping from dynamic mapping %@ with which to map object representation: %@", mapping, representation);
            return nil;
        }
        // Make sure the destination of a core data relationship is the right entity class for the object we're mapping;
        if ([self.destinationObject respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)])
        {
            NSEntityDescription *destinationEntity = [self.destinationObject entity];
            NSDictionary *destinationPropertiesDictionary = [destinationEntity propertiesByName];
            NSRelationshipDescription *destinationPropertyForDestinationKeyPath = [destinationPropertiesDictionary valueForKey:relationshipMapping.destinationKeyPath];
            NSString *relationshipDestinationClassName = [[destinationPropertyForDestinationKeyPath destinationEntity] name];
            NSString *mappedObjectClassName = [NSString stringWithCString:class_getName(concreteMapping.objectClass) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            if (![relationshipDestinationClassName isEqualToString:mappedObjectClassName])
            {
                return nil;
            }
        }
```

...